# JS: Automatizar conexión a la API de YouTube

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Estoy haciendo pruebas con la API de YouTube para que a partir de mi página web se puedan crear listas de reproducción.

El código lo he obtenido de aquí:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests

El proceso implica una autorización inicial, como se puede ver en este fragmento HTML:

```
  <div id="login-container" class="pre-auth"> <!--Autorización-->
    This application requires access to your YouTube account. Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
  </div>
```

Al hacer clic en `<a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a>`, aparece el siguiente modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No voy a detallar el código necesario para ello -se puede consultar en el enlace que he adjuntado al principio del mensaje-, pero una vez el usuario elige qué cuenta quiere usar puede crear listas de reproducción en el canal de YouTube **asociado a dicha cuenta de correo**.

Bien, por el modo en el que funciona mi página web, quiero que todos los usuarios de ella creen sus listas en mi canal de YouTube y **sólo en mi canal de YouTube**, por lo que me pregunto si hay alguna manera de "puentear" este proceso de autorización de manera que sea totalmente invisible para el usuario; es decir, que cualquier petición que reciba la API de YouTube desde mi web sea autorizada a través de la cuenta de correo de Gmail asociada a mi canal de YouTube sin que el usuario tenga necesidad -ni posibilidad- de utilizar otra.

Comment: La mejor forma de hacer esto es mediante una [Cuenta de Servicio](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). Tendrías que configurarla en la Consola de Google, obtener las autorizaciones, ponerlas del lado del servidor (GCP te da un archivo JSON con la autorización) y usar [la biblioteca del cliente](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples) con el que trabajes en backend (PHP, Java, Phyton ...). Gestionarías todo desde el backend sin necesidad de pedir autorización al usuario.

Comment: Sí, del lado del servidor trabajo con PHP. Elegí hacer esto con JS porque me pareció más amigable.

Comment: Todo puede ser *amigable* si lo programas bien. Pero, trabajar desde el servidor es más seguro (no tienes que exponer tus credenciales, ni tu API Key por ejemplo) y puedes hacer más cosas con mayor facilidad, entre otras, lo que quieres precisamente: usar la API sin que pida autentificación al usuario. Imagina por ejemplo que quieres registrar cosas al respecto en la BD, pues lo tienes a mano, porque estás en el contexto del servidor. Las ventaja son muchas, sólo que al principio parece un mundo configurar y demás, pero cuando lo logras, vas sobre ruedas.

Comment: Configurar una Cuenta de Servicio consiste básicamente en: 1. Crearla (en la consola de Google), y autorizar para esa cuenta las APIs que quieres usar (YouTube en este caso); 2. Descargar el archivo de autorización (cuando creas la cuenta te indica dónde descargar el archivo); 3. Guardar ese archivo en una carpeta segura del servidor; 4. Instalar la biblioteca del cliente (en este caso PHP). Si usas composer, con una línea de comando instalas la biblioteca; 5. Programar tu código (en PHP), para eso puedes mirar los ejemplos de la doc, que suelen ser bastante buenos y, cualquier problema: SO.

Comment: Vaya, parece que no hay código de ejemplo para autorizar solicitudes con PHP.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *autorizar solicitudes*?

Comment: Supongo que pueda encontrarlo aquí: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client.

Comment: Algo como esto: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests

Comment: Si configuras una Cuenta de Servicio no necesitas hacer eso realmente (lee lo que dice el enlace de mi primer comentario atentamente para comprender lo que es una cuenta de servicio). Luego, en la página de la API te explica paso a paso lo que tienes que hacer para preparar tu entorno y finalmente muestra ejemplos básicos del código para conectar en backend y a partir de ahí, a disfrutar usando la API. Y, si hay alguna duda, Stackoverflow, planteando tu duda concreta y mostrando el código.

Comment: En todos los ejemplos de la documentación te muestra un código para crear el cliente ([he aquí uno de los ejemplos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#create_a_playlist)). Si analizas el código, ahí le suministras las credenciales (desde el banckend), de modo que el usuario no tiene que intervenir en nada ni autorizar nada.

Comment: Todo el código para crear las listas de reproducción y añadirles canciones lo tengo hecho en jQuery, supongo que no sea necesario rehacerlo con PHP.

Comment: Sí, tienes que escribirlo en PHP, estamos hablando de que **gestionarás todo lo que tenga que ver con la API desde el backend**. Luego usarás el cliente (Javascript, jQuery) solamente para las cuestiones de la vista (mostrar respuestas del resultado de las operaciones, errores, etc), y para recoger datos que el usuario suministre.

Comment: Por cierto, leyendo la documentación de la librería de PHP (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts) he encontrado lo siguiente: "Some APIs (such as the YouTube Data API) do not support service accounts."

Comment: Interesante apunte, no lo sabía. En ese caso, te puede servir un tipo de autorización llamado [`OAuth 2.0 server-side`](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html). La verdad es que no tengo experiencia con este tipo de autorizaciones, yo uso en mis proyectos Cuentas de Servicio (no uso la API de Youtube). [Aquí hay más detalles sobre OAuth en la API de Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps?hl=es).

Comment: Ese tipo de autorización parece que implica la intervención del usuario también: "La aplicación redirige al usuario a una dirección URL de Google[...]".

Comment: Todo lo que encuentro implica pedirle permiso al usuario: "The following steps show how your application interacts with Google's OAuth 2.0 server to obtain a user's consent to perform an API request on the user's behalf. Your application must have that consent before it can execute a Google API request that requires user authorization." https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-web.md#using-oauth-20-for-web-server-applications

Comment: No sé, creo que lo que yo quiero hacer debería ser más sencillo puesto que no necesito acceder a información del usuario...

Answer (score 1):

Si solo se agregaran las listas de Youtube a tu canal lo que puedes hacer es crear un token en
[Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard)

#### Sigue los siguientes pasos

1. Panel de Google Cloud

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Buscar Youtube en la barra de búsqueda y habilitar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Crear credenciales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. ID de cliente OAuth
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, esas credenciales ya las tengo creadas desde hace un año, cuando empecé a trastear con la API. ¿Cuál sería el siguiente paso?