# PHP: Automatizar conexión a la API de YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Como ya abordé en anteriores mensajes (en [español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510875/js-automatizar-conexi%C3%B3n-a-la-api-de-youtube) y en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003026/accessing-youtube-data-api-without-user-intervention)), estoy intentando automatizar la conexión a la API de YouTube de manera que el usuario de mi página web, cuando cree una lista de reproducción a partir de ella, no tenga que autorizar el proceso y éste ocurra siempre en mi canal de YouTube (asociado a mi cuenta de Gmail) y no en el suyo.

La primera y principal sugerencia que recibí en los anteriores mensajes fue que cambiase de JS a un lenguaje de servidor; en mi caso, PHP. En SO Internacional también me dijeron que necesitaba hacer uso de "refresh tokens". No he llegado tan lejos, sino que, hasta el momento, sólo he estado analizando el código de ejemplo de Google para crear listas de reproducción usando PHP:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#php

```
<?php

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google API Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // This code creates a new, private playlist in the authorized user's
    // channel and adds a video to the playlist.

    // 1. Create the snippet for the playlist. Set its title and description.
    $playlistSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet();
    $playlistSnippet->setTitle('Test Playlist  ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $playlistSnippet->setDescription('A private playlist created with the YouTube API v3');

    // 2. Define the playlist's status.
    $playlistStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistStatus();
    $playlistStatus->setPrivacyStatus('private');

    // 3. Define a playlist resource and associate the snippet and status
    // defined above with that resource.
    $youTubePlaylist = new Google_Service_YouTube_Playlist();
    $youTubePlaylist->setSnippet($playlistSnippet);
    $youTubePlaylist->setStatus($playlistStatus);

    // 4. Call the playlists.insert method to create the playlist. The API
    // response will contain information about the new playlist.
    $playlistResponse = $youtube->playlists->insert('snippet,status',
        $youTubePlaylist, array());
    $playlistId = $playlistResponse['id'];

    // 5. Add a video to the playlist. First, define the resource being added
    // to the playlist by setting its video ID and kind.
    $resourceId = new Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
    $resourceId->setVideoId('SZj6rAYkYOg');
    $resourceId->setKind('youtube#video');

    // Then define a snippet for the playlist item. Set the playlist item's
    // title if you want to display a different value than the title of the
    // video being added. Add the resource ID and the playlist ID retrieved
    // in step 4 to the snippet as well.
    $playlistItemSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItemSnippet();
    $playlistItemSnippet->setTitle('First video in the test playlist');
    $playlistItemSnippet->setPlaylistId($playlistId);
    $playlistItemSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);

    // Finally, create a playlistItem resource and add the snippet to the
    // resource, then call the playlistItems.insert method to add the playlist
    // item.
    $playlistItem = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem();
    $playlistItem->setSnippet($playlistItemSnippet);
    $playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->insert(
        'snippet,contentDetails', $playlistItem, array());

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>New Playlist</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $playlistResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $playlistResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>New PlaylistItem</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $playlistItemResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $playlistItemResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Playlist</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Intentaré resumir el proceso porque es un tanto complejo:

La clave, creo yo, está en el `if` de una estructura condicional if/elseif/else que da comienzo en la **línea 56** y en el que se gestiona la creación de la lista de YouTube en sí una vez se ha producido la autorización:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
...
}
```

`$client` es un objeto, creado a partir de la clase `Google_Client()` en la **línea 28**, que controla el proceso de autorización, y al que se le ha de pasar (líneas 29 a 34) el id de cliente y el secreto OAuth 2.0, extraídos ambos de la consola de Google, el alcance y la URL de redirección (que en este caso es una dirección en local para hacer pruebas).

Con un `var_dump()` de ese `$client->getAccessToken()`, tras haber completado todo el proceso de autorización, se ve lo siguiente:

```
array (size=5)
  'access_token' => string 'ya29.A0ARrdaM_98xxxxx' (length=163)
  'expires_in' => int 3599
  'scope' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube' (length=39)
  'token_type' => string 'Bearer' (length=6)
  'created' => int 1652648250
```

Vais a ver varias `xxxxx` a lo largo del mensaje; aclaro que no corresponden a exactamente cinco caracteres sino a muchos más.

Secuencialmente lo que ocurre es esto:

**1)** Antes de la autorización, el flujo discurre por el `else` (de la estructura condicional if/elseif/else ya mencionada) de la **línea 134**:

```
else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
```

Se genera un número aleatorio, `$state`, se le pasa a `$client` y, además, se crea una sesión con él, `$_SESSION['state']`. Esto forma parte de un mecanismo de seguridad posterior (anterior en el código, ver el paso 4) que no tengo muy claro para qué sirve.

La clave de este paso es la creación de una URL de autorización, `$authUrl`, con la siguiente estructura:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
?
response_type=code
&
access_type=online
&
client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Frecopilatorios%2Fphp%2Fweb%2Fyoutube_php%2Findex.php
&
state=2064393417
&
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube 
&
approval_prompt=auto
```

**2)** Esta URL se incluye en el `href` de un enlace HTML que insta al usuario a autorizar el proceso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede comprobar en la **línea 154**, todo lo que ve el usuario se controla a través de una variable, `$htmlBody`, cuyo contenido varía según avanza el proceso.

**3)** Este enlace despliega un modal, donde se ha de indicar con qué cuenta de Gmail se va a autorizar la conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, esto es lo que realmente quiero "trampear", de manera que este modal nunca se despliegue, sino que por defecto se utilice siempre la misma cuenta (la tercera en la imagen), que es la que tengo autorizada en la Consola de Google y a la que está asociada el canal de YouTube que quiero utilizar para que todos y cada uno de los usuarios de mi web creen sus listas de reproducción.

La URL del modal es muy similar a la anterior, pero se le añade un `/oauthchooseaccount` al principio y otro `&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow` al final:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount
?
...
&
flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

Supongo que las credenciales de la cuenta de correo se envían al servidor vía POST. Ni idea de en qué formato, claro.

**4)** Una vez has elegido la cuenta apropiada, se genera una nueva URL:

```
http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/youtube_php/index.php
?
state=2064393417
&
code=4%2F0AX4xxxxx
&
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube
```

`code` es la clave aquí, puesto que es lo que permite acceder al `if` de la **línea 41**:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
```

Aquí está el mecanismo de seguridad que comprueba que el `state` proporcionado por la URL coincide con la sesión creada en el paso 1.

Además, se autentica el `code` con un método de `$client` y se crea una sesión con `$client->getAccessToken()`. `$tokenSessionKey` se genera en la **línea 40**, justo antes de este `if`.

**5)** Esta nueva sesión se comprueba luego en el `if` de la **línea 51**:

```
if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}
```

Donde se llama a otro método de `$client` que "setea" el toquen de acceso a partir de la sesión.

Y esto nos lleva de vuelta al principio de la explicación, el `if` de la **línea 56**, al que se entra con `$client->getAccessToken()` simplemente. Hay una especie de proceso recursivo por el cual `$client->getAccessToken()` sirve para crear `$_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]`, que a su vez sirve para "setear" el toquen en `$client` de manera que finalmente sólo haga falta `$client->getAccessToken()` para crear la lista de YotuTube.

**Resumiendo**: Mi objetivo es que al hacer clic en el enlace inicial (en mi página web será un botón "Publicar") no se despliegue el modal sino que automáticamente la API de YouTube reciba la petición desde mi cuenta de Gmail, la autorice y, en consecuencia, la lista de reproducción se cree siempre en mi canal de YouTube.

Si alguien ha sido capaz de leer hasta aquí, muchas gracias: ¿alguna sugerencia?